# Populate text within cdata from another xml

Tags: xml, cdata

First XML - `mainfood.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE doc [
<!ENTITY fooditems SYSTEM "foodnames.xml">
]>
<content>

<section name="pages">

    <page name="food">

    <texts>

<pageText> <![CDATA[
<font face="arial">food</font>
]]></pageText>

<pageText><![CDATA[
&fooditems;
]]></pageText>


</texts>
        </page> 

</section>


</content>
```

Second XML - `foodnames.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<a >• <font face="Georgia">chicken biryani<br></a></font>
<a >• <font face="Georgia">manchurian<br></a></font>
<a >• <font face="Georgia">aloo dum<br></a></font>
<a >• <font face="Georgia">sushi<br></a></font>
```

Basically I want the lines like `<a >• <font face="Georgia">chicken biryani<br></a></font>` to be read from `foodnames.xml` and populated into `mainfood.xml` in place of `&fooditems;`

But the code is not working...

Answer (score 0):

CDATA explicitly stops markup from having any effect. You cannot use entities inside a CDATA block (that is half the point of having CDATA, the other half is to stop tags having any effect).